# Convert astropy table to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, astropy

I have an astropy.table.table object holding stars data. One row per star with columns holding data such as Star Name, Max Magnitude, etc.

I understand an astropy table's internal representation is a dict for each column, with the rows being returned on the fly as slices across the dict objects.

I need to convert the astropy table to a Python list of dict objects, with one dict per star. Essentially this is both a transposition of the table and a conversion.

I can obviously iterate through the table, by column within row, to build the dicts and add them to the list, but I was hoping there was a more efficient way?'

Comment: Could you add some data samples?

Comment: Thanks, will add a sample but am away atm so be a few days.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an idea.  I'm not sure if you can be much more efficient, except if the table is big it might be better to convert to a pure Numpy array first with `.as_array()`:

```
In [1]: from astropy.table.table_helpers import simple_table

In [2]: t = simple_table()

In [3]: t
Out[3]: 
<Table length=3>
  a      b     c  
int64 float64 str1
----- ------- ----
    1     1.0    c
    2     2.0    d
    3     3.0    e

In [4]: names = t.colnames

In [5]: [dict(zip(names, row)) for row in t]
Out[5]: 
[{'a': 1, 'b': 1.0, 'c': 'c'},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 2.0, 'c': 'd'},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 3.0, 'c': 'e'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more compact and memorable way, you can convert the table to pandas.DataFrame and use `to_dict` method of pandas DataFrame. It may not be most efficient to copy the table into a new object, but depending on the format you want to convert to, pandas can be much more convenient. Astropy tables have a convenience `to_pandas` and `from_pandas` methods.

```
>>> from astropy.table.table_helpers import simple_table
>>> simple_table().to_pandas().to_dict(orient='records')
[{'a': 1, 'b': 1.0, 'c': 'c'},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 2.0, 'c': 'd'},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 3.0, 'c': 'e'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up iterating, slicing and copying as list which worked fine on the relatively small dataset.